# How to Filter a txt file in java

Tags: java, design-patterns, filter, stream, text-files

As input i have a File containing a list of rooms.
Each room has the following information: (1 line of the file)

```
ID;name;phonenumber;PIN e.g.:
1234;A 0.12;1234;123456789 (ID is same as [first] phonenumber)
2345;A 0.12;2345;123456789 (A room can have more than 1 phonenumber - in a new line like in the example)
```

Now i need a java program which returns a list like this:

> ```
> Example Input:
> 1127,A 0.01,1127,1
> 2476,A 0.01,2476,1
> 2309,A 0.01,2309,1
> 2306,A 0.01,2306,1
> 2706,A 0.01,2706,1
> 2757,A 0.01,2757,1
> Generates Output:
> 1127,A 0.01,1127,2476,2309,2306,2706,2757,1
> ```

ID;name;phonenumber1;...;phonenumberN;PIN

This code (without main function) adds a second phone number to the existing one, if the rooms from 2 lines are the same.

```
public static String duplicateNumbers(String s, String x) {

    String result = s;
    if(compareString(s, x)) {
         result = result.substring(0, 21)
                 + x.charAt(21) + x.charAt(22) + x.charAt(23) + x.charAt(24) 
                 + result.substring(20); 
    }
    return result;
}

public static boolean compareString(String s, String x) {
    for(int i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
        if(s.charAt(i) != x.charAt(i)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

ß

Comment: What is the question? Also, the txt format looks like CSV and you can use a library like OpenCSV to parse rather than writing the entire code yourself.

Comment: I need a java program which gives me the result as return type. My own program is already 300 lines of code but i have no idea how to solve that.

Comment: you can use hibernate as mentioned here https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/csv-jdbc-hibernate.rst

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is gonna be helpful for what you need. I used Apache Common CSV. You can find more info here https://www.baeldung.com/apache-commons-csv
    
    **File.csv**

```
    ID;name;phonenumber;PIN;
    1127;A 0.01;1127;1;
    2476;A 0.01;2476;1;
    2309;A 0.01;2309;1;
    2306;A 0.01;2306;1;
    2706;A 0.01;2706;1;
    2757;A 0.01;2757;1;
    2722;B 0.01;2722;1;
    2723;B 0.01;2723;1;
```

**Unit Test in Spring Boot**

```
@Test
public void testForAlphaOmega() throws IOException {
    @Getter
    class ROOM {
        String id;
        String name;
        String phoneNumber;
        String pin;

        private ROOM(String id, String name, String phoneNumber, String pin){
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
            this.pin = pin;
        }
        private ROOM(CSVRecord record){
            this.id = record.get("ID");
            this.name = record.get("name");
            this.phoneNumber = record.get("phoneNumber");
            this.pin = record.get("PIN");
        }
    }
    try (
        Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("....PATH_OF_FILE"));
        CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT
        .withHeader("ID", "name", "phoneNumber", "PIN")
        .withIgnoreHeaderCase()
        .withFirstRecordAsHeader()
        .withDelimiter(';')
        .withTrim())
    ) {
        List<ROOM> rooms = new ArrayList<>();
        csvParser.getRecords().stream().map(ROOM::new).collect(groupingBy(ROOM::getName)).forEach((key,val) -> rooms.add(new ROOM(val.get(0).getId(), val.get(0).getName(), val.stream().map(ROOM::getPhoneNumber).collect(Collectors.joining(",")),val.get(0).getPin())));
        rooms.forEach(item -> System.out.println(item.getId() + ";" + item.getName() +";" + item.getPhoneNumber() + ";" + item.getPin()));
    }
}
```

**Result**

```
    2722;B 0.01;2722,2723;1
    1127;A 0.01;1127,2476,2309,2306,2706,2757;1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
String fileName = "D:/test.txt";

try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {

  stream.forEach(System.out::println);

} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```